# Cloud Firestore returning undefined in events

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

Everyone.

I'm trying to make a script that creates data in Cloud Firestore and returns it. But I can't access the data (undefined), why?

That's my script:

```
const tools = require('./bin/firebase');
const app = require('express')();
// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000);

const db = tools.connectFirebase();

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  const ipAddress = socket.handshake;

  console.log(ipAddress.address);

  db.collection('socket').doc('refresh').collection('2').doc('1').set({
    name: 'Los Angeles',
  });

  db.collection('socket').doc('refresh').onSnapshot((doc) => {
    console.log('Current data: ', doc.data());
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Disconnected.');
  });
});
```

And that's what this script returns:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soJhz.png)

And finally, that's the Cloud Firestore data that I wanted to return: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWwqL.png)

I need to return those nodes, so: Basically, I need something like this:

```
{
    1: {
        name: "Los angeles:",
    },
    2: {
        name: "Washington DC",
    },
}
```

Basically, I need to fix it, anyone can help me to deal with it?

(Sorry about my English skills, I'm trying to improve it)

Comment: What's this ./bin/firebase thing? do you have access to `db`?

Comment: Yes, I do. It's just a simple connection script that returns something like this: `admin.initializeApp(CONFIG_FIREBASE).firestore();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this below. Your set method is returning before the data is written. It's returning a future(promise). You have to wait on it either with `.then()` or `await` to be able to read the data back.

```
  db.collection('socket').doc('refresh').collection('2').doc('1').set({
    name: 'Los Angeles',
  }).then(() => db.collection('socket').doc('refresh').onSnapshot((doc) => {
    console.log('Current data: ', doc.data());
  }));
```

Edit: oh sorry, you are reading /socket/refresh, which is probably empty. The subcollections under it are not sent as a json as you described above. You have to do `db.collection('socket').doc('refresh').collection('2').doc('1')` to read them. You cannot get a subtree as a json like you expected.

Go ahead and put some data into /socket/refresh and hopefully it's not going to be undefined anymore.

Comment: Still returning `undefined`.

Comment: Basically, is there a way to get a subtree as a json? That's what I need, actually, just like Realtime Database does.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way.

Comment: Well, you can technically write a cloud function that will prepare that for you with multiple calls to Firestore.